# systemd-resolve fails to resolve hostnames when using bind9

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, systemd, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I set up `bind9` inside a docker-container that I want to use as the dns-server. The container is running fine and will resolve correctly if queried with `dig`.

Running `dig` on the host-machine (not from inside the container):

```
dig @localhost google.com +short
142.250.185.78
```

Also bind9 is correctly resolving my own zone (example):

```
dig @localhost myexample.com +short
213.133.98.98
```

The issue I am facing is that `systemd-resolve` fails to use `bind9` as its dns:

```
ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I configured `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` to use localhost as DNS, I had to disable the DNSStubListener because it would clog port 53:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1
DNSStubListener=no
```

Also I set `/etc/netplan/00-config.yaml` to use localhost as nameserver:

```
network:
  nameservers:
    addresses:
      - 127.0.0.1
```

Running `systemd-resolve --status` gives the following output, indicating that localhost is being used as DNS:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
         DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1   
  
Link 2 (enp1s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS            
DefaultRoute setting: yes            
       LLMNR setting: yes            
MulticastDNS setting: no             
  DNSOverTLS setting: no             
      DNSSEC setting: no             
    DNSSEC supported: no             
         DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1
```

So why can't I resolve hostnames, e.g. by using `ping`? The bind9 dns is working as intended and will resolve correctly if directly addresses via `dig @localhost`. Also `systemd-resolve` is configured to resolve via localhost but fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by getting rid of `systemd-resolved`:

```
systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

Comment: I have a bind9 container listening on the host's IP (and working) when I  'dig @127.0.0.1 www.com' but apt can't resolve anything. Weird.